# Change Windows Close, Maximize, and Minimize button colors

Tags: windows-10, colors, themes, user-interface

### Greetings, fellow Super Users!

I want to change the Windows 10 title bar buttons (The X, square, and -) colors.  However, I do not know how.  If anybody knows how to do this, can you please share.  These are the buttons that I mean:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked Settings, Personalization, Colors? Scroll down the right side and review / enable Show Accent Color on (a) Start and (b) Title bars.    The buttons you show will change colors actively as you hover over them. I do not think you can otherwise natively change their colors

Comment: That is not what I mean (yes I did try that anyways).  I want to change the color of the X, Square, and -.

Comment: I do know what you mean, but there is no native way to change those specific colors. Those squares are unique fonts and do not change natively

Comment: Is there any way to change the font color?  to edit the font manually?  Or to do so with Regedit?

Comment: Not manually. Changing the Registry is a great way to cause problems, so I do not use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using
[Windows themes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-themes),
with which you may customize just about every aspect of Windows.

However, this is a complex subject, and creating themes as XML files is not for
everyone, so using a third-party product is recommended.

Perhaps the best product in that area is
[Stardock WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/),
which is however trialware (although not very costly).

Comment: Is there a free alternative?

Comment: Themes can be created using a text editor, so WindowBlinds is only a convenience. You could perhaps try the trial version of [Stardock Curtains](https://www.stardock.com/products/curtains/) (30-days trial) that also contains a themes editor. It might be possible to save the created XML file and keep it after the trial period ends. You may also use Windows Sandbox to undo the installation of the trial version, after saving the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use curtains that change the max min buttons (-, [], and X). If you are using Windows 11, then use window blinds. Or use themes that can change the buttons' appearance. Altogether, there are 2 Stardock apps and 1 Windows app. The total is 3.